# Failure while connecting to SQL Server: “The driver received an unexpected pre-login response”

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I have a web application that, alongside a Windows Service, connects to a MS SQL Server 2017 using Hibernate. This connection have already been tested and executed correctly in previous situations, that is, compatibility between driver and server are fine. Despite this, I'm having trouble doing a particular connection to a new, remote SQL Server (note: remote SQL connections were already successfully done in the past).

So this remote SQL Server 2017 is located in a cloud server. In my PC, I have NetBeans running the tested web application. In another server, but in the same network, I have my Windows service installed.

With the Windows service, I'm able to connect to the server in the cloud. If I run it in inside the cloud server, it connects to it as well. I'm also able to connect to it using Microsoft SQL Management Studio, both from within the cloud server as well as from my PC. In other words, I'm perfectly able to connect to the server thus I have the correct connection informations.

The only exception here is my web application; it just won't connect. And when it fails to do so, it throws this error message: "The driver received an unexpected pre-login response. Verify the connection properties and check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. This driver can be used only with SQL Server 2005 or later."

Here is Hibernate configuration (remember: I was previously able to connect to remote SQL 2017 servers):

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://ip.goes.here\MARTIN2:1521;databaseName=DATABASENAMEHERE</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">login</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
```

Since this problem was occurring, I tried lots of other possible combinations of configuration in the code above and none of the was successfull.

So why is this happening? The only extra stuff that maybe could explain this is that in the same cloud server there is another Oracle server installed. Nevertheless I don't believe this is the problem since, as I mentioned, both MS Studio as well as the Windows service are able to connect without problem. Driver is mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar. This web application connects fine in another SQL Server installed in a different machine in the network (the same mentioned above from where the Windows service connectin was tested), testifying once again driver compatibility is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer to the problem.

First, I needed to take out the port information. It seems that the installation of the SQL server was somewhat buggy and therefore the default 1433 port wasn't used, but rather some other I still don't know yet. So removing the specific call to use 1433 solved the connection error. (Note: in the above code I use 1521 because the Oracle server in the same machine was using this port and I previously mistakenly though the same port was going to be used; only later I noticed it was my mistake).